# How to stop iTunes from automatically re-downloading?

Tags: itunes, macos

I have deleted my iTunes application (using a terminal command) several times already and it keeps popping back up. I have to delete it every time it downloads.

Is there a way to stop iTunes from automatically downloading?

Answer (score 1):

To stop iTunes from automatically downloading, you should completely uninstall it from your computer. Simply follow the steps:

1. Open Activity Monitor on your Mac and kill the process "iTunes-Helper".
2. Open Terminal and type:
   "sudo rm -r /Applications/iTunes.app".